# Laptop monitor brightness goes to zero randomly

Tags: laptop, display, brightness

I have a strange problem with my HP Pavilion laptop. The brightness of screen goes randomly zero but everything else work perfect. increasing brightness of screen doesn't change anything. If you turn an external light in front of laptop display, I can see the content. I checked in Both Windows(7) and Linux (Ubuntu) the same problem happens. I need to logout or change resolution to be able to use the computer again.

I guess it is a hardware defect. What is your idea?

Comment: Is there any possibilites your laptop has its own Light detector and automatically adjust luminosity ?

Comment: no, I have it for more than 4 years and this problem never happened.

Comment: What is the frequency that this problem occurs ? Every time you turn your laptop on or it happens randomly ?

Comment: it happens randomly almost every day. sometimes it happens twice an hour,  sometimes it doesnt happened for 5 hours ...